# How to get layout viewport width for IE 9 on WP7

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to get layout viewport size for IE 9 on WP7. Now the problem is that website layout according to [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) is bigger than  element (how is that even possible?)

$('window').width() or window.getSize().x always give 1024px (visual viewport size). **[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html#link5)** advises to use **document.body.clientWidth**, but that also gives 1024px.

Also tried creating div with width: 100%, but it only gets size of body (1024).

I'm running out of options how to get it and also why is body size limited?

PS: not using metatags.

Comment: you need the width and height of user's window?

Comment: I need layout viewport (size of html)